# getting the equal button work in j query instead of showing full equation

Tags: jquery, eval, calculator, equals

I am trying to get my calculator to function like a normal calculator (i am new to this what is posted below is help from another user on here) I have played with the code messing with the #calculation function but every time i try to change it everything breaks. what is happening is that when i type in a number it shows up with the number i put in with and equal sign and then the number i put in as the answer what i am trying to figure out is how i can make this calculator work normally for example i push 3 and only 3 shows up then + and then another number then i hit equals and i get an answer

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var expression = "";
    function appendChar(char) {
    expression += char;
    var result;
    try {
     result = eval(expression);


    $("#calculation").text(expression + " = " + result);
    } catch (e) {

    $("#calculation").text(expression);


    }
}



    $(".digit, .operator").click(function()    {
        appendChar($(this).text());
    });

    $(".clear").click(function()    {
        expression = "";
        $("#calculation").text("0");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement a calculator I suppose. If so you have to put your entered numbers in an array, then when someone presses a sign, keep it separately. Then start getting second sequence of numbers until you key `=` sign.

Implementation of a calculator is not that easy specially if you consider negative numbers. However, there are some libraries you can use. Below is one example:

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/javascript-css3-calculator